# How can I find out what process last accessed a file in linux?

Tags: linux, pid

I'm trying to find out what process or automatically running program access a certain .txt. This file seems to be updated every day at 8:00 and while that's fine, the issue is that I need to find what specific process updates the file every morning so that I can trouble shoot it. If possible I'd like to do it without installing any other applications or Daemons (Such as audit).

Comment: Hard to guess what you consider to be "other" applications and therefore will refuse to accept. Is `lsof` "other"? `fuser`? `lastcomm`? `inotifywait`? Your question is like a game where you're the only one who knows the rules.

Comment: While that's not strictly answering the question, I would consider looking into your `crontab` files, or even the `syslog`, for an easy clue. Requires just a pager. ;)

Comment: I should mention that I don't know that much about the system and I'm not really willing to install things willy nilly. That being said, Worse comes to worse, I'll install `audit` if I need to.